# Enemy road properties

Tags: civilization-4

**Does movement on enemy roads use your technology level or that of the enemy?**

There are several technologies that improve the uses of roads (crossing rivers with Construction, another that gives +1 to movement on roads).  Does a unit traveling on enemy roads (using the Commando promotion) benefit from the technology of his enemy, his own technology, or both?  Using the enemy technology level would be the most intuitive and visually consistent, since the ability to cross rivers is called *bridge-building*, and is represented by tiny bridges graphically.  Using your own technology, on the other hand, is more consistent with how units work in general.  Which is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested this using the scenario builder.  I created a spy in enemy territory on one side of a river and on a road that crosses over it.  I gave the enemy construction, resulting in them having bridges.

[image]

Crossing the bridge resulted in expenditure of the spy's one movement point.  Thus, **they did not use the benefit of the enemy's technology even though it is represented as a bridge.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unit can not use the technology of the enemy.

However units can use the technologies of allies, i.e move faster in ally territory.

Comment: Since your units can use enemy roads with the promotion, I don't think that broad a statement holds. I think the question includes the subquestion, "Will my units with the promotion benefit from enemies switching to railroads?", for example.

Comment: @oKtosiTe I would not be shocked to find out that the answer is actually different between those two scenarios - a road and a railroad are different types of tile improvements, while +1 roads or a river-crossable roads are the same type of improvement as regular roads, but modified by your current tech level.  Maybe.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not a _very_ advanced player so I stand corrected, but I'm glad my point came across.